# Is this question to access a logo of a space related organization on topic here?

Tags: support, questions

Is the following question on topic here?

> I find the Zero G logo with *the scientist experiencing zero gravity and stars in background* deeply inspiring and would like to use for private purposes (e.g. for an avatar). I can find only pictures of the [Airbus A300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A300) airplane with this logo, is it available in its original format or a better close-up?

[image]

If it is no way on topic, where to ask?

Comment: If you need help identifying the plane or it's owner, you can ask that on [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/). If you'd like some legal advice about using logos or other intellectual property as avitars, there is [Patents SE](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) and also [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) to consider.

Comment: The logo belongs to Novespace. You can find it on their website and [various sources](http://www.iafastro.org/societes/novespace/)

Comment: Thank you so much  Richard!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question is not on topic - you are asking for reuse of a trademarked logo. For something like that you must ask the logo owner